# How do we get to hyperlink an entire reference when using a mix of varioref, hyperref, cleverref and nameref?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref

Using a combination of the packages `varioref`, `hyperref`, `cleverref` and `nameref` we can get sophisticated cross references (technically 'references' to 'labels'), complete with hyperlinks.

For example, from a Minimum Working Example (MWE) as follows ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{nameref}

\newcommand{\smartref}[1]{\nameref{#1} \vref{#1}}

\begin{document}

\pagebreak
\section{The Start}\label{theStartLabel}


\pagebreak
\section{Section Two}\label{sectionTwoLabel}


\pagebreak
\section{Varioref with hyperref and 
cleverref}\label{variorefWithCleverfAndHyperrefLabel}

Varioref with hyperref and 
cleverref:

See \vref{theStartLabel}\\
See \vref{sectionTwoLabel}\\
See \vref{variorefWithCleverfAndHyperrefLabel}\\
See \vref{theEndLabel}\\

Custom command using varioref, hyperref, cleverref and nameref:

See \smartref{theEndLabel}


\pagebreak
\section{The end}\label{theEndLabel}

\end{document}
```

... we get ...

[image]

How would we change the MWE in order to get the `varioref` command `\vref` and the custom command `\smartref` to have the hyperlink extend to the entire reference.

E.g. So we get ...

> ...
>   See [section 4 on the next page](http://#)
>   ...
>   See [The End section 4 on the following page](http://#)
>   ...

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use the `\hyperref[label]{text}` user macro from the `hyperref` pacakge.

The solving MWE ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{nameref}

% Store \vref in a variable to enable redefining itself.
% Redefine \vref so the hyperlink is extended to the entire
% reference.
\let\vrefpointer\vref
\renewcommand{\vref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{\vrefpointer{#1}}%
}

% A custom command \smartref with the hyperlink extended to 
% the entire reference. 
% Plus some grammatic sugar (quote marks and comma)
\newcommand{\smartref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{\cref{#1}, ``\nameref{#1}", \vpageref{#1}}%
}


\begin{document}

\pagebreak
\section{The Start}\label{theStartLabel}


\pagebreak
\section{Section Two}\label{sectionTwoLabel}


\pagebreak
\section{Varioref with hyperref and 
cleverref}\label{variorefWithCleverfAndHyperrefLabel}

Varioref with hyperref and 
cleverref:

See \vref{theStartLabel}\\
See \vref{sectionTwoLabel}\\
See \vref{variorefWithCleverfAndHyperrefLabel}\\
See (\smartref{theEndLabel})\\

Custom command using varioref, hyperref, cleverref and 
nameref:

See \smartref{theEndLabel}\\

\pagebreak
\section{The end}\label{theEndLabel}

\end{document}
```

... which produces ...
[image: Minimum Working Example solution output.]

I came across this solution from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#.5Chyperref rather than the package documentation. There may well be a more elegant solution (that, for example, exposes a better range of possible customizations) but this one works.

Update01: edited my custom \smartref command to include trailing comment characters (%) in order to prevent rogue spaces bracketing the command output.

Update02: edited solution MWE to have bracketed output `See (\smartref{theEndLabel})\\` in order to make clear there are no rogue spaces at the endpoints of my custom \smartref command. Changed the output image to reflect.

Update03: end of line comment characters `%` to \vref renewcommand.